# Is there a difference between passing event and $event?

Tags: javascript

The following JavaScript function works if I pass `event` but I get error if I pass `$event`. What is the difference between the two and why doesn't `$event` work?

```
function IWasClicked(event) {
    alert("clicked again with event",event);
}
```

This doesn't work and give `$event` is not defined at `HTMLAnchorElement.onclick`

```html
<div id="about"><a class="selected-button" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="IWasClicked($event)">About</a></div>
```

this works

```html
<div id="about"><a class="selected-button" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="IWasClicked(event)">About</a></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `event` is a [standard global variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event)
- `$event` is not.

So you get a reference error when using `$event` because nothing has caused it to be declared.